# Setting Focus on TextBox from ViewModel in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am having a master window in which there are plenty of user control. and using navigation i am able to access the user controls. But by question is how to set focus on the first text box when ever the user control is opened.

I tried with dependency property and boolean flags, i was able to succeeded a bit. When i first render the UserControl i was able to focus but when i open for the second time i was not able to set focus on the TextBox.

And one more thing, i have validation for TextBoxes, if the validation fails then the textbox should be emptied and the focus should be on the respective text box.

How can i achieve this using MVVM in WPF (CLR 3.5, VS2008)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a UserControl then you also have CodeBehind.

Place this inside your codebehind and you will do fine.

```
this.Loaded += (o, e) => { Keyboard.Focus(textBox1) }
```

Place this inside your UserControl XAML if you wish to listen to validation errors.

```
<UserControl>
 <Grid Validation.Error="OnValidationError">
  <TextBox Text{Binding ..., NotifyOnValidationError=true } />
 </Grid>
<UserControl>
```

Inside the CodeBehind of your UserControl you will have something like this:

```
public void OnValidationError(o , args)
{
  if(o is TextBox)
  {
    (TextBox)o).Text = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use AttachedProperty to stick to MVVM pattern it'll keep your view model independent of UI code and fully unit testable. Following attached property binds a boolean property to focus and highlight the TextBox, if you do not want the highlighting then you can remove the highlighting code and just work with focus code.

```
public class TextBoxBehaviors
    {
        #region HighlightTextOnFocus Property

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightTextOnFocusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HighlightTextOnFocus", typeof (bool), typeof (TextBoxBehaviors),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(false, HighlightTextOnFocusPropertyChanged));

        public static bool GetHighlightTextOnFocus(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool) obj.GetValue(HighlightTextOnFocusProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHighlightTextOnFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HighlightTextOnFocusProperty, value);
        }

        private static void HighlightTextOnFocusPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,
                                                                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uie = sender as UIElement;
            if (uie == null) return;

            if ((bool) e.NewValue)
            {
                uie.GotKeyboardFocus += OnKeyboardFocusSelectText;
                uie.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftButtonDownSetFocus;
            }
            else
            {
                uie.GotKeyboardFocus -= OnKeyboardFocusSelectText;
                uie.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseLeftButtonDownSetFocus;
            }
        }

        private static void OnKeyboardFocusSelectText(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null) return;

            textBox.SelectAll();
        }

        private static void OnMouseLeftButtonDownSetFocus(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null) return;

            if (!textBox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
            {
                textBox.Focus();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

You can use this attached property in on your TextBox which you want to focus/highlight...

```
<TextBox ... local:TextBoxBehaviors.HighlightTextOnFocus="{Binding IsScrolledToEnd}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [FocusManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement.aspx)

```
<UserControl>
 <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding Path=FocusedTextBox, ElementName=UserControlName}">
  <TextBox x:Name="FocusedTextBox" />
 </Grid>
<UserControl>
```